# Binding to model change event not working in view in backbone.js

Tags: events, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm creating a very simple backbone app to familiarize myself with the framework. All is working except for binding of model change events to a function in my view. I've checked previous questions on SO and none have helped.

My Model has one variable 'counter'. View has 2 buttons which increment or decrement model's 'counter'. Simple stuff. That's all working fine, but when I try and listen for model change events in the view, I only receive notification once -on model creation (when defaults are created, I assume).

I know that counter is being updated because if I manually call render after updating the model I can see the effect, but in the interest of better mvc-ish structure, I want to view to be notified of change events and to update itself.

Below is the coffeescript code.

```
  $ ->

      class Count extends Backbone.Model

           defaults: counter : 0

           change: -> console.log('changed')


      class Spinner extends Backbone.View

           el: $('#counterView')

           initialize: =>

                @model = new Count()
                @model.bind 'change' , @update()

           events:
                'click button#incBtn' : 'inc'
                'click button#decBtn' : 'dec'

           inc: ->

                @model.set counter : @model.get('counter') + 1

           dec: ->

                @model.set counter : @model.get('counter') - 1

           update: ->

                console.log('update')
                $('#num').html(@model.get 'counter')

      view = new Spinner()
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="counterView">
        <button id="incBtn">Increment</button>
        <button id="decBtn">Decrement</button>
    <div id="num">Number</div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.
b

Answer (score 5):

Your error is here:

```
@model.bind 'change' , @update()
```

What you're telling it is to bind the `change` event to what `@update()` *returns*, when you want to bind it to `@update` *itself*. So it should be:

```
@model.bind 'change' , @update
```

(Without the brackets). As it were, `Spinner.update` would execute immediately on `Spinner.initialize`, exactly as you found out. A few more notes:

- It's unnecessary to wait for `document.ready` to create your classes. You could do that first (outside of `document.ready`), and only instantiate the models, views etc on `document.ready`.
- It seems kind of weird to create a new model *inside* of your view. You probably want to do something like this instead:

  ```
  view = new Spinner(model: new Count)
  ```

**Edit:** As [Trevor Burnham notes below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482950/binding-to-model-change-event-not-working-in-view-in-backbone-js/9484379#comment12010456_9484379), you want the fat arrow `=>` on `inc`, `dec` and `update`. Fixed below.

Taken together:

```
class Count extends Backbone.Model

     defaults: counter : 0

     change: -> console.log('changed')


class Spinner extends Backbone.View

     el: '#counterView'

     initialize: =>

          @model.bind 'change' , @update

     events:
          'click button#incBtn' : 'inc'
          'click button#decBtn' : 'dec'

     inc: =>

          @model.set counter : @model.get('counter') + 1

     dec: =>

          @model.set counter : @model.get('counter') - 1

     update: =>

          console.log('update')
          @$el.find('#num').html(@model.get 'counter')

 $ ->
     view = new Spinner(model: new Count)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Linus. Unfortunately it hasn't remedied the problem. The view is still not being notified of model changes. The model is being updated , and the change event being dispatched as before, but the view's update function just never hears about it.

Comment: You're sure `console.log('update')` doesn't run? I'm seeing a problem right after that: `@model.get 'counter'` won't work, because `@update`'s context will be lost when you pass it to `@model.bind`. Easy fix: Define `update` with a fat arrow (`=>`).

Comment: Thank you both for the input, but still no luck. Linus one small catch regarding document ready. The view is using a jquery selector as the element $('#counterView') so either the class needs to be defined on doc ready, or the el needs to be passed as an argument to the consctructor as you've done with model ; new Count. Thought I should point that out in case anyone else attempts to play with this code. ie. either $ -> needs to be before class Spinner or additional argument passed to constructor eg . view = new Spinner(model : new Count ,  el: $('#counterView') )

Comment: @user1237615 right, you should probably just specify the selector string there anyway (`#counterView`) and reference `this.$el` afterwards [check Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after some fiddling, the following is working. For some reason, when the model is updated, it fails to dispatch the event back to the view so I'm manually dispatching a change event from the model with:

```
 @trigger('change')
```

Pretty clunky, but it's the only thing that works for me.

I also noticed quirky behaviour when using defaults, so I'm now setting counter with initialize (rather than through defaults). To see the unintended behaviour with defaults, uncomment defaults and comment out initialize. It's like change event is not dispatched whenever counter = original value of 0.

```
class Count extends Backbone.Model

      #defaults: counter : 0

      initialize: ->
           @set counter : 0

      change: ->
           @trigger('change') #this lil fella made it work

 $ ->
      class Spinner extends Backbone.View

           el: $('#counterView')

           initialize: =>
                @model = new Count
                @model.bind 'change' , @update
                @update()

           events:
                'click button#incBtn' : 'inc'
                'click button#decBtn' : 'dec'

           inc: =>
                @model.set counter : @model.get('counter') + 1

           dec: =>                    
                @model.set counter : @model.get('counter') - 1

           update: =>                    
                $('#num').html(@model.get 'counter')


           view = new Spinner()
```